# Can I import Tensorflow to Raspberry pi 3 B+ GPIO with 'import tensorflow as tf'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, raspberry-pi3

I hope to make an electronic project where I connect electronics with Tensorflow, and I decided to use Raspberry pi 3 B+. I previously used Arduino. On the Raspberry Pi GPIO is for electronics, is it possible for me to connect GPIO with Tensorflow by using "import tensorflow as tf?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the latest announcement from [@TensorFlow](https://twitter.com/TensorFlow).

> It's been our goal since we launched to run on as many platforms as
>   possible. We're happy to announce that it's now easier than ever to
>   install TensorFlow on your @RaspberryPi!

Learn more in [@petewarden's](https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-1-9-officially-supports-the-raspberry-pi-b91669b0aa0?linkId=55070050) post